# Using Generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am curious about Generics in C# and would like to know your opinion

- do I correctly use Generics
- about how to improve this code

For example, I have a payment system of some shop.

So I have `PaymentSystem` class:

```
public class PaymentSystem
{        

    public T MakePayment<T>(T paymentSystem) where T : PaymentCompany
    {
        try
        {
            paymentSystem.CalculatedSum = paymentSystem.CalcSum();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;

        }

        return paymentSystem;
    }
}
```

and abstract class for `PaymentCompany`:

```
public abstract class PaymentCompany
{
    public PaymentCompany(decimal amount)
    {
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public decimal CalculatedSum { get; set; }        

    public virtual decimal CalcSum()
    {
        return Amount;
    }

}
```

and payment companies:

```
public class MasterCard : PaymentCompany
{
    public MasterCard(decimal amount) : base(amount)
    {

    }

    public int CVV { get; set; }


    public override decimal CalcSum()
    {           
        return (base.CalcSum() + 5)/0;
    }

}


public class Visa : PaymentCompany
{
    public string KeyWord { get; set; }

    public Visa(decimal amount) : base(amount){}
}
```

And I call `MakePayment` method like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var paymentSystem = new PaymentSystem();
     var result = paymentSystem.MakePayment(new MasterCard(15));     
}
```

Guys, make a please code review, and answer to my questions:

- do I correctly use Generics
- how to improve this code(should I handle exceptions in derived classes(`MasterCard`, ...))

All replies will be highly appreciated!

Comment: That divide by 0 could cause problems.  Not so sure you need generics for this.

Comment: @Paparazzi but what would you use instead of Generic?

Comment: Generics allow you to create strongly typed code that can be reused with many different types. I find it mostly useful for low-level, high-reuse code. The sort of code you'll find in standard libraries: collections, tasks, Linq, and so on. In your case, sure, due to generics `MakePayment<Visa>(visa)` gives you a result of type `Visa`, but you already had a `Visa` reference in the first place (the argument you passed in), so what's the point?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet  Sorry, what do you mean `MakePayment<MasterCard>`  instead of `MakePayment<Visa>`? 
In my view, the point to use Generics here is to use reusable, generic method `MakePayment<T>` which can work with various type inherited from `PaymentCompany`.

Comment: @StepUp: you don't need generics if you want to accept derived types: `MakePayment(PaymentCompany company)` will accept `Visa` or `MasterCard` instances just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the wrong assumption that you must return the updated payment company because you are changing the value of `CalculatedSum`. `PaymentCompany` is a class and therefore a reference type. The reference doesn't change when you modify fields and properties of the object it is referencing.

`MakePayment` can have a `void` return type and does not need to be generic.

```
public class PaymentSystem
{        
    public void MakePayment(PaymentCompany paymentCompany)
    {
        try
        {
            paymentCompany.CalculatedSum = paymentCompany.CalcSum();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var paymentSystem = new PaymentSystem();
     var company = new MasterCard(15);
     paymentSystem.MakePayment(company);
     decimal result = company.CalculatedSum;
}
```

---

But the design is not optimal. What is the property `CalculatedSum` good for? Drop it and return the result directly!

```
public class PaymentSystem
{        
    public decimal MakePayment(PaymentCompany paymentCompany)
    {
        try
        {
            return paymentCompany.CalcSum();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var paymentSystem = new PaymentSystem();
     var company = new MasterCard(15);
     decimal result = paymentSystem.MakePayment(company);
}
```

---

Another option is to have `CalcSum` with a void return type and instead let it assign the `CalculatedSum` internally. `CalculatedSum` would then have a private setter.

```
public abstract class PaymentCompany
{
    public PaymentCompany(decimal amount)
    {
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public decimal CalculatedSum { get; private set; }

    public virtual void CalcSum()
    {
        CalculatedSum = Amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your apply! S there is no need to use Generics in this case?

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question, because your payment system is hypothetical and does not make a lot of sense (there is a method `CalcSum` which does not calculate a sum. What is the task of the payment system? Just to catch exceptions of `CalcSum`? Etc., etc.).
While inheritance allows you to create specialized classes with specialized functionality, generics allow you to create different versions of a class with the same functionality but applied to different types. A good example is `List<T>`. You can create lists with the same functionality but storing different item types.